# FBAudienceNetwork crash with iOS 7.0.1 version in iPad Only

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I implemented Facebook ads in iOS App, Ads is displaying correctly in all device but only crashing into iPad version lower then iOS 8 here i add error and some code for displaying ads.

> *** Assertion failure in +[FBScreen sizeInOrientation], /Users/chrisp/src/ios-sdk3/ads/src/FBAudienceNetwork/FBAudienceNetwork/util/FBScreen.m:85
>   2016-12-02 21:49:22.606 -[__NSCFString containsString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x160d6150
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminate_handler unexpectedly threw an exception

Code for Displaying ads.

```
fbadView = [[FBAdView alloc] initWithPlacementID:@“ID”
adSize:kFBAdSizeHeight50Banner
rootViewController:self];

[fbadView loadAd];

CGSize size = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size;
CGFloat xOffset = size.width / 2 - 150;
fbadView.frame = CGRectMake(xOffset, 10, 300, 50);

[self.mainscrl addSubview:fbadView];
```

Comment: can you show the code for related this containsString condition in your class

Answer (score 0):

> -[__NSCFString containsString:]:

The function `containsString` is available in iOS 8 and above. That's why it is raising an exception in iOS 7.

You need to make iOS 8 as your minumum deployment target. Alternatively you can do something like this:

```
NSString *testString = @"Test";
BOOL containsString = [testString rangeOfString:@"testString"].location != NSNotFound;
```